# 10k Tools keeps on showing all the flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools

It annoys once you have reviewed flagged questions and answers in `Review->Tools`, it should not show again unless there is some edit in the post.

To search for a valid flag, you need to read same question dozens of time, when you load next 50.

There should be a provision "Not to show already seen posts"

Comment: In the 10k flag tools, as long as a I *take action* on the flag (whether it is to flag the post, or to "dispute" it), it does not show up for me again. Are you not seeing this behaviour, or are you asking for some sort of "ignore" option?

Comment: @Matt: I want the post I read should not come again. As one I skipped it, why it should come again?